# Python Cython compatibility between different python versions?

Tags: python, cython, compatibility

First sorry if the question doesn't fit. English is not my native language. So i'll try to explain.

1. Let's presume i have python 3.9 installed on my PC
2. So, with setup.py i build .so files. These .so files will work on others PC with python 3.9 installed only, but it will not work on PC with python 3.8 or python 3.11 installed.

My code is compatible across python 3.8-3.11.

How you solve this? Or better question is, is it possible to solve this?

Build command:
`python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`

I suppose if i want to work on other python version i need to build with:

```
python3.8 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3.9 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3.10 setup.py build_ext --inplace
and so on...
...
```

But this is unacceptable for me. Because i need to install a lot python versions on build computer and ship separately each package.

---

If is not possible another question is; is there some alternative?

What's the point here?

The point is i need to convert python code to machine code, which need to work no matter what minor python version is on target computer (3.8, 3.9, 3.10 or 3.11).

Cython is great, and i would like to continue with cython, but this 'issue' is no go for me.

Comment: If building lots of extensions for different Python versions is unacceptable to you then Cython is not currently suitable for you. It's really that simple

Comment: So, what is an alternative?

Comment: Nuitka comes to mind. It's not exactly what you want in this question but it's a good way to make your code portable.

Comment: Nuitka and Mypyc do similar things (but I think have the same restriction). If you're trying to call external C code then you could use CFFI or ctypes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look, I think there are other solutions for resolving this problem, one I really recommend to you, is to use `python 3.9` (or higher now, I don't know which you're using now) and make your code normal for `python 3` with cython normally. Then import `3to2`. With this library you can translate the `python 3` for `python 2`, for the translation I think you need to open the command prompt and write

`python -w 3to2 local\of\your\file.extension`

sorry but I can't be a hundred percent right, you need to try it. With your code in `python 2`, you just need to use a web translator to make your code of `python2` in `python3`, and probably your code will work in any `python3` version.

Another idea I have is to use other libraries, like me, I use `python 2.7` and I just can't use tkinter, so I use Tkinter, it is different, yes, but it is translatable.